# How to actively reset the NSUrlSession delegate

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

As stated in the iOS networking lesson, it is advised that there only exist one NSURLSession object within the life time of the application. I have set up a singleton class, and enable multiple controllers to call the class and obtain the NSURLSession to create tasks. However I would like the view controllers to implement the NSURLSessionDataDelegate protocol and set the NSURLSession's delegate accordingly in order to handle received data within that particular context.

Comment: Where did you read you can only have one? I create them per class or just one offs all the time.

Comment: "An NSURLSession object manages multiple tasks, each of which represents a single URL request and any follow-on requests. You usually create a session when your app launches, then create tasks in much the same way that you would create NSURLConnection objects."

Comment: There isn't anything that prohibits you from creating new sessions, it is just not the way it was intended to be used.

Comment: That certainly is one way to do it. In that case, you can implement the delegate methods per class, and set the class to the delegate when it loads.

Comment: when create task you need to save task identifier by "taskIdentifier" property of NSURLSessionTask. in NSURLSessionDataDelegate you again get "dataTask.taskIdentifier" and use this taskIdentifier to ident what controller to delegate to.

Comment: Oh yes that sounds like what I was looking for.. Thanks

Comment: Make that an official answer if you want your virtual points..